# System of first order homogeneous ODEs?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, homogeneous-equation

Consider
$$
\begin{pmatrix} M_1' \\ M_2' \end{pmatrix}
= \begin{pmatrix} g_1 & g_1 \\ f_2 & g_2 \end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix} M_1 \\ M_2 \end{pmatrix},
$$
where $f,g, M$ are unknown real-valued function of one variable.

Q1: Is it solvable, if the initial points are non zero?

Q2: I ran sympy to solve the equation, and had the form
$$
m_1(t) = C_1 x_0(t) + C_2 x_0(t) \int \frac{f_1(t) e^{\int g_1(t) dt} e^{\int g_2(t) dt}}{x_0^2(t)} dt
$$
and
$$
m_2(t) = C_1 y_0(t) + C_2 \left( y_0(t) \int \frac{f_1(t) e^{\int g_1(t) dt} e^{\int g_2(t) dt}}{x_0^2(t)} dt + \frac{e^{\int g_1(t) dt} e^{\int g_2(t) dt}}{x_0(t)} \right)
$$
What are $x_0$ and $y_0$?

Comment: The solution of a differential equation $f'(t) = A f(t)$ (here $f = (M_1, M_2)^T$, $A = \begin{pmatrix} g_1 & f_1 \\ f_2 & g_2 \end{pmatrix}$) always depends on the initial conditions of the form $f(x_0) = y_0$. For example consider $f'(t) = f(t)$. All functions $x_0 \cdot e^{t}$ for some $x_0 \in \mathbb R$ solve this ODE, but a unique solution can only be obtained if we add the condition $f(0) = 1$. Then the unique solution is $f(t) = e^t$.

Comment: Thank you very much. I assumed that A is not hermitian matrix(and hence not positive definite matrix) and initial points are not zero. Can you let me know the specific conditions under which the equation is solvable?